# AES SBOX Masking in Python

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, finite-field, s-boxes, cryptographic-hardware

I am trying to create an AES Sbox masking based on [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/134.pdf) paper. In the paper, they tried to mask the sbox described in [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45760-7_6.pdf) other paper. The inversion is been done in GF(4). I know that it is mostly implemented in hardware, while the software implementation requires use of EEA or sbox table. However, I am implementing it in python anyway but stuck in the process. The below code is for the first part of the AES Subbyte, I haven't computed the second part - Affine Transformation. Can someone who is vast in this field assist with any hint on how to implement the SBOX generation and its masking based on the first paper?

```
def hex_to_binary(hex_digit):
# Convert hexadecimal to binary and remove the '0b' prefix
binary_equivalent = bin(int(hex_digit, 16))[2:]

# Ensure the binary representation is 8 bits long
binary_equivalent = binary_equivalent.zfill(4)

return binary_equivalent

def main():
try:
    # Get user input for two hex digits
    hex_digit1 = input("Enter the first hex digit: ").upper()
    hex_digit2 = input("Enter the second hex digit: ").upper()

    # Convert hex digits to 8-bit binary equivalents
    binary1 = hex_to_binary(hex_digit1)
    binary2 = hex_to_binary(hex_digit2)

    bin_combi = binary1+binary2
    print(bin_combi)
    inverse_4(bin_combi)
    # Display the results
    print(f"Binary equivalent of {hex_digit1}: {binary1}")
    print(f"Binary equivalent of {hex_digit2}: {binary2}")
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter valid hexadecimal digits.")

def inverse_4(bin_combi):
a0 = int(str(bin_combi)[7:8])
a1 = int(str(bin_combi)[6:7])
a2 = int(str(bin_combi)[5:6])
a3 = int(str(bin_combi)[4:5])
a4 = int(str(bin_combi)[3:4])
a5 = int(str(bin_combi)[2:3])
a6 = int(str(bin_combi)[1:2])
a7 = int(str(bin_combi)[0:1])

aA = a1 ^ a7
aB = a5 ^ a7
aC = a4 ^ a6

al0 = aC ^ a0 ^ a5
al1 = a1 ^ a2
al2 = aA
al3 = a2 ^ a4

ah0 = aC ^ a5
ah1 = aA ^ aC
ah2 = aB ^ a2 ^ a3
ah3 = aB

inverse_8(ah0, ah1, ah2,ah3,al0,al1,al2,al3)

def inverse_8(ah0, ah1, ah2,ah3,al0,al1,al2,al3):
aA = al1 ^ ah3
aB = ah0 ^ ah1

a0 = al0 ^ ah0
a1 = aB ^ ah3
a2 = aA ^ aB
a3 = aB ^ al1 ^ ah2
a4 = aA ^ aB ^ al3
a5 = aB ^ al2
a6 = aA ^ al2 ^ al3 ^ ah0
a7 = aB ^ al2 ^ ah3

print(f'S_8: {a7}{a6}{a5}{a4}{a3}{a2}{a1}{a0}')
```